# Send a variable with axios in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, axios

Good morning,

I don’t know if my title is understandable but I would like to be able to have a const with parameters to be able to choose what to send with axios. 
Basically i have this :

```
const {send1='', send1_1= '', send2='', send2_2 = '' } = this.state;

await axios.post(' MY_API/default/serverlessAppFunction', 
{ key1: `${send1}, ${send1_1}`, key2: `${send2}, ${send2_2}`},);
```

I would like to know if it was possible to declare a variable somewhere else, to put it in axios.
A little bit like this :

```
const key3 : `${test3}, ${test3_3}`;

const {send1='', send1_1= '', send2='', send2_2 = '', test3= '', test3_3=''} = this.state;

await axios.post(' MY_API/default/serverlessAppFunction', 
{ key1: `${send1}, ${send1_1}`, key2: `${send2}, ${send2_2}`, key3},);
```

The example it's not working of course.

But globally, i would like to do a thing like that.
And if it's possible, How do I declare this variable and in what form?

i'm talking about declare like this or in another way

```
const key3 = "${test3}, ${test3_3}";
```

(Sorry if I’m not specific, I don’t speak very well English)
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you face any issue?? Mention that issue in your question?

Comment: If you want your state to be available globally you can use redux for the state management, is there any issue with the example you provided in the question?

Comment: @PardeepSharma i have updated my post with a question. I don't know if it's really understandable :/ sorry if it's not

Comment: @YogeshDevgun i want to know how can i declare the key3

Comment: const key1 = ` ${send1}, ${send1_1} ` ;

const key2 = ` ${send2}, ${send2_2} ` ;

const key3= ` ${send3}, ${send2_3} ` ;

await axios.post(' MY_API/default/serverlessAppFunction', 
{ key1, key2, key3},);

You can declare like this as constants and use anywhere.

Comment: @YogeshDevgun it was that. Thank you.  But I don't know how to put your comment in "green" sry.

Comment: @ThibaultCastille I have answered in answer section to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare like this as constants and use anywhere:

const key1 = `${send1}, ${send1_1}` ;

const key2 = `${send2}, ${send2_2}` ;

const key3= `${send3}, ${send2_3}` ;

```
await axios.post(' MY_API/default/serverlessAppFunction', { key1, key2, key3 });
```

It is shorthand for:

```
await axios.post(' MY_API/default/serverlessAppFunction', { key1: key1, key2: key2, key3: key3 });
```

Hope that answers your question.